# Query all user's name who are not friends to each other

Tags: sql

Friendship database contains two tables, one that keeps track of all the users, another maintains friendship relationships
between users

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE friends (
    ID1 int,
    ID2 int
);
```

For each friendship there is exactly one entry in the friends table, containing the primary keys in users of the two friends.

And i want find names of all users who are not friends to each other

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66511e/1

```
select users1.Name, users2.Name from users As users1 inner join users As users2
    on users1.id > users2.id
    where not exists 
           (select * from friends 
                          where (friends.id1 = users1.id and friends.id2 = users2.id)
                              or(friends.id2 = users1.id and friends.id1 = users2.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from users where id not in (
    select id1 from friends
    union all
    select id2 from friends
) a
```

I assumed that you don't have `NULL` entries in `friends` table, that's important because:

> However, if the right-hand table contains a `NULL` in the values being filtered by `NOT IN`, an empty result set is returned, potentially giving unexpected results.

[Reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83684/except-operator-vs-not-in)

Comment: your answer result is: find all users that has no friends